# Is One Obligated to Honor Parents if it Involves a Loss of Income?

Tags: halacha, money, employment, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

One is not obligated to pay for items in order to honor parents since the obligation is "mishel av" - from the parents assets.

However, is a child obligated to service / nurse a parent if that involves staying away from work and losing income -- that was not earned yet? Or, is unearned income viewed the same as losing already earned income and the child is not obligated?

Sourced answers only, please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh Deah siman 240 siff 5 says one is required to lose work in order to honor his parents, even though this will cause the child to end up needing to collect money for himself. However, this is only when the son has money to support himself that day, if he does not have even that much, he does not have to lose work.

Comment: I dont understand this. Isn't מניעת רווח also a הפסד? That's how the Mechaber paskens regarding חול המועד.

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv I think you got it backwards. מניעת רווח is not דבר האבד for חול המועד.

Comment: @DoubleAA the rosh in moed koton